# Display selected text in Bootstrap dropdown form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap drop down menu inside a form. By default it displays 'DROPDOWN' but if I select something from the list it will not show the selected value and/or `<li>`. How do I get the dropdown menu to show the value I've selected instead of showing 'DROPDOWN' everytime I select a new value.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Last Name" value="">
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Team</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is my HTML code. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your question displaying correctly?

Comment: What do you want it to happen when you select something from the dropdown?

Comment: Amended the question, I want it to show the value I select. What happens is that the value I select doesn't display, instead it just shows 'DROPDOW' everytime.

Comment: Can you check the snippet in my answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add an `id` to your dropdown menu like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="mydd">
```

You need to use some code like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("#mydd a").click(function () {
    $("#dropdownMenu1").html($(this).html() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  });
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#mydd a").click(function () {
    $("#dropdownMenu1").html($(this).html() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" value="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Last Name" value="">
          </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Team</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Dropdown
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="mydd">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason your one looks exactly the way I want it however my looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/CTWzX Do you know what my issue is?

Comment: No errors, the weird thing is that it's also capitalised which I didn't choose for, please see the full code for the page: http://pastebin.com/UZjvWF7B

Comment: Never mind, I've managed to fix it, thanks for your assistance.